# Replacing Text in a String Sometimes Not Working in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, replace

In a Windows application I'm building using Python and Tkinter, I am trying to replace parameters in a SQL query with input variables that a user inputs.  For example, here is a query with the parameters delineated by "${" at the beginning and "}" at the end.

There is one large text widget where the user pastes the query.  Then they click a button and the application finds all of the instances of these parameters and puts them into a column of individual text boxes, one for each parameter.  There is another column of text widgets to the right of the parameters and those are the variables that the user wants to substitute for the parameters.  When the user clicks another button, the app is supposed to do the replacement of the parameters with the relevant variables.  (Variable 1 goes into anyplace where Parameter 1 is in the query, etc.)

Unfortunately, in the query below, only the 2nd parameter, ${objNum}, gets populated.  I think the issue has something to do with the fact that Parameters 1 and 3 are string parameters and have the parameter inside single quotes while Parameter 2 doesn't have the quotes.

How can I replace all the parameters with the correct variables?

All ideas and/or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Please let me know if any further information is needed.

````
 select objective_number, 
    objective_name, 
    objective_desc,
    objective_type,
    weight,
    quota,
    earnings_potential,
    payout_capped
from objectives
where key = '${key}'
and objective_number = ${objNum}
and objective_type = '${objType}'```



What DOES work is if I put literals in the replace() method.  But that can happen only once because I need to be able to grab whatever the user has put in the Variable text widgets.

It just won't work with variables for the parameters inside the single quotes.
I have a function that executes when the user clicks on the button to replace the parameters with the variables.  

The Parameter text widgets are named:
param1
param2
param3


The Variable text widgets are named:
var1
var2
var3


For the first row of text widgets, I get the value from parm1 and put it into a variable called parmStr and I put the value from var1 into a variable called varStr.  The next one would take values from parm2 and var2, etc.


If the user puts "var1" in var1, "var2" in var2 and "var3" in var3, here is the result.  As you can see, only var2 got populated correctly.

select objective_number, 
    objective_name, 
    objective_desc,
    objective_type,
    weight,
    quota,
    earnings_potential,
    payout_capped
from objectives
where key = '${key}'
and objective_number = var2
and objective_type = '${objType}'
````